# WebView loading Url

Tags: android, webview

So I'm working on adding some web view stuff and will eventually make this more complicated but for now am just trying to get the basics working. I have my xml built and such and I am inflating it on top of another view. So its in like a dialog box.

```
web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.WebView);

name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Hydrogen.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.web);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        web.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + name.getText().toString());

        RelativeLayout btn = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                        }
            });     
        dialog.show();
}});
```

Basically thats my code regarding the WebView etc. The problem is on line 145 which is the web.loadUrl line. I'n not sure whats wrong but every time I try to open the Dialog it crashs. Thanks.

```
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at table.periodic.Hydrogen$1.onClick(Hydrogen.java:145)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-16 17:16:08.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I also just tried making a seperate project in which to load the web page. Just a WebView loading the URL. It partly worked. It worked to the point that it opened the URL but it did it inside the browser instead of inside the webview. Could be because I named the WebView browser but will try more.

Comment: we'll need a stack trace for sure.

Comment: @jorgesys I've added the error message. I'm assuming that is what you and Nick are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found it out myself. My dialog code had to looks as follows.

```
name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Hydrogen.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.web);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            eleweb = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.eleweb);
            eleweb.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + name.getText().toString());
            eleweb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

            RelativeLayout btn = (RelativeLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                });     
            dialog.show();
    }});
```

the problem what that I wasn't calling the WebView in a dialog format. Once I got all the WebView information loading inside the Dialog and did

```
eleweb = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.eleweb);
```

it worked.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

for

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: Yes. I have internet permission

Comment: No difference. Still crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Throw in a breakpoint and make sure that your webview is not null when you try attaching it. The only way it would be crashing is if your webview is null. **Make sure the name reflects the component webview that you are refering to in your xml layout file**.

Comment: Can you explain that a little more. Not sure I get what you are saying.

Comment: insert a break point in your code, run a debug mode and have it STOP execution BEFORE it hits the problem. Then in Debug mode look at what all the variables are at the instant before it reaches the crashing point. Insure that NONE of the variables you are using are null.

Comment: @JoxTraex I'm not really sure what you mean but I know that everything is named properly. For some reason it just doesn't want to open the URL. I can get the dialog to open without the WebView but once I add the WebView it crashes at  web.loadUrl("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + name.getText().toString());

Comment: I think I see whats wrong, the name you gave gave your WebView object in your xml is the same name as the WebView class. Delete that line and make sure that you are not pulling from the android R file and instead insure that you are pulling from your file. If that doesn't work then you might just have to post your XML and CODE so that we can run through it to insure you're doing it properly.

Along with this change the name of the webview to something like this web_view just to make sure you're not using the wrong reference.

Comment: Also if you want, i'm sure this problem could be solved in a matter of minutes. Being that, I would be happy to help you one-on-one in a chat room that I could create if you still can't solve the problem. Ideally would help if you sent me the source, so I can help you debug. Or just send me the code in question.

Comment: I tried changing the name but it doesn't seem to have helped. Let me know what will work best and I'll do what I can to provide it. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you are here in 1 hour (9:13pm PST) join my room called namethatbug! or whenever, just ping me

Comment: @JoxTraex Whenever your available I have some stuff posted in the chat. Until then I'll be tweaking stuff trying to figure it out.